# Creating a BAT loop to process all *.mkv files in a Directory with ffmpeg-normalize

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg

Hoping someone can help here. I'm on Windows 7

I'm trying to use [ffmpeg-normalize](https://github.com/slhck/ffmpeg-normalize) to process a bunch of mkv movies to report on loudness.

The command is `ffmpeg-normalize "FILE PATH" -n -p`

What I'd like to do is have a variable for FILE PATH so that it can use a directory, say G:\Movies for all mkv files and then loop it into ffmpeg. I'm using the >> to write the output to a text file

I've read up on loops [here](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) but I'm just not understanding how to apply it to this situation

It seem so simple but I just can't do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
cd "G:\Movies"
for %%a in (*.mkv) do (
  ffmpeg-normalize "%%~fa" -n -p >>"Out_%%~na.txt"
)
exit /b 0
```

Will create output files in syntax "Out_Filename.txt"

Comment: Thanks so much!!